# How to get the HTTP request method on a Grizzly-embedded Jersey application?

Tags: java, http, rest, jersey, grizzly

I am working on a JAX-RS application. Before, I had it as a WAR mounted on a Tomcat server and I was obtaining the HTTTP Request Method using: `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getMethod()`.

However, now I'm working with an embedded Grizzly server on my application and have found the following error on startup:

```
Missing dependency for constructor public wci.api.resource.AudioSessionResource(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) at parameter index 0
```

All my resources extends a `MyHappyCustomResource` class that has a constructor which receives an `HttpServletRequest`, provided by the resource constructor via Injection.

This is an example of a resource constructor, the `super` call is from `MyHappyCustomResource`:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public AudioSessionResource(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    super(request);
    this.dao = new AudioSessionDao(this.sessionManager.getCurrentSession());
}
```

Right now I need this just to get the HTTP-Method so, any other or more correct way to do it it's appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use Grizzly's Request class as told by this page on the Grizzly official site:

https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html

> Similar abstractions to those offered by the Servlet specification: HttpHandler (Servlet), Request (HttpServletRequest), Response (HttpServletResponse).

Comment: I do not understand why this had such good review. The link provided has several examples of handling post data, but does not actually answer the question. There is no method described in the text the link refers to that allows one to use the Request class to determine whether a request is GET or POST.

Comment: It is helpful for a lot of people. It is not explicit but implicit on that link. The fact that there is not an exact line of code to copy and paste does not mean that the information presented is not enough to solve the problem. It was for me and the people who vote it. If you can't understand this I don't see why you should blame the answer for not being enough to solve your problem.